# Completely uninstallation LAMP

Tags: apt, apache2, lamp

I just install LAMP by using a command line. `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

it's work! then I needed to uninstall them so I tried to `sudo apt-get remove lamp-server^`

by the way, It's show me to messages below....

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libsdl1.2debian-alsa
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common bluez-cups cups cups-driver-gutenprint cups-pdf foo2zjs gdm gdm-guest-session
  gecko-mediaplayer gnome-applets gnome-control-center gnome-media gnome-mplayer gnome-panel gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon goldendict gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
  hpijs hplip hplip-cups indicator-applet indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-applet-complete indicator-sound libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasound2-plugins libcanberra-pulse libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhpmud0 libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient16
  libnet-daemon-perl libphonon4 libplrpc-perl libpulse-browse0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libqtwebkit4 libsane-hpaio libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libsnmp15
  libwrap0 mplayer mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf pulseaudio-utils pxljr python-speechd speech-dispatcher splix
  ssl-cert tcpd vlc-plugin-pulse
```

What's going on? I have to remove pulseaudio, mplayer and gdm ? Is it concerned with LAMP?

next, I try to using a command line `sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2` 
These result yield...

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:   apache2*
```

Is it safe for do like this? I intend to completely uninstall LAMP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By trying to purge lamp-server with aptitude, its trying to remove cups and other system utilities. that's what's resulting in all the other removes. You can remove the individual packages on their own: `aptitude remove apache2 php5 mysql-server`

This will remove the `apache2` server, `php5`, and the `mysql-server` parts of LAMP.  Afterwards, you can remove unneeded packages.  However, do let me know if this triggers the long list of other removals, because if it does we may need to rethink the methods used to remove the server package(s).